# Unity: How to pause my game-timer and present time result on "finished game" screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good evening guys!

I've got a little problem. I am creating a Pacman-ish game, and I have created a timer which pops up and appears on the top corner of the screen which presents the current time passed since the first scene started.

I am struggling with making the timer stop at my Game-over Scene

Do you have any tips for solutions that might work?

I am very new to C# and Unity, so please have that in mind, and sorry for any inconvenience!

Thank you so much in advance!

(Oh, and btw, I have made another script for the timer to continue through scenes, and to not replicate itself when the game restarts, so that part is ok for now)

```
public Text timerText;
private float startTime;
private bool finnished = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (finnished)
        return;

    float t = Time.time - startTime;

    string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
    string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");

    timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;

}


public void Finnish()
{
    finnished = true;
    timerText.color = Color.yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try an event:

**Subscribe to the stopEvent event delegate:**

```
public Text timerText;
private float startTime;
private bool finnished = false;

GameManager.stopEvent += Finnish;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!finnished)
    {
        float t = Time.time - startTime;

        string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
        string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");

        timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
}


public void Finnish()
{
    finnished = true;
    timerText.color = Color.yellow;
}
```

**Inside a script (let's say, GameManager.cs or something), you create the event and delegate:**

```
public delegate void EventHandler();
public static event EventHandler stopEvent;
```

**Your Scene Loading Code (For example, could be called from a loading code in GameManager.cs)**

```
//// scene is done
stopEvent();
```

**You can store the timer result in singleton, perhaps a GameManager.cs file that is a singleton, which lives across scenes.**

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That really makes sense. Is it possible to somehow trigger Finnish() on a specific scene? I understand how to trigger it on a button click, but not when "finish-scene" loads

And do you have any tips on how to eventually print the result time in the "finish-scene"?

I really appreciate it mate!

Comment: I recommend putting your scene code somewhere else, like a Game Manager. I kinda laid it out a bit above.  Maybe check  out something like this for further info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5p2JlI7PV1w

Comment: More info on delegate events here: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/events-uh#5c894782edbc2a1410355442

Comment: Okay Kale, thank you! I will watch and read the tutorials, I might post again tomorrow if i get stuck

Answer (score 1):

Ok Kale_Surfer_Dude, so I have sort of figured out how to trigger Finnish(); upon entering either of my two finish/goal scenes, but somehow, it doesn't trigger when i die or finish.

Do you see why?

```
public Text timerText;
private float startTime;
private bool finnished = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time;

    // Creating temporary reference to current scene
    Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

    // Retrieve the name of this scene.
    string sceneName = currentScene.name;

    if(sceneName == "Goal" || sceneName == "MenuOnCollision")
    {
        Finnish();
    }

    // Retrieve the index of the scene in the project's build setting
    int buildIndex = currentScene.buildIndex;

    // Check the scene name as a conditional
    switch (buildIndex)
    {
        case 4:
            Finnish();
            break;
        case 6:
            Finnish();
            break;
    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!finnished) {

        float t = Time.time - startTime;


        string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
        string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");

        timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

}


public void Finnish()
{
    finnished = true;
    timerText.color = Color.yellow;
}
```